# Sequelize, How to change value after the instantiation?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize instantiation

```
new Sequelize('xxxx', 'xxxx' , null, {
    host: null,
    dialect: "xxxx",
    operatorsAliases: 0,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
```

And i want to change a certain value afterwards,
like =>

```
my_instance_sequelize.host = 'new_xxxx'
```

but that don't change my value.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Sequelize instance is basically creating a connection with the database. Changing host value afterwords is not going to change the connection. It requires creating a new instance.

So, if you want to change the `host` value of the Sequelize instance, you essentially wants to create a new instance.

Comment: Seems right, but for my purpose i don't think i gonna work. What i want to do is let the customer (user of my platform) connect to his own database. And i will retrieve the sequelize instance every time to access to his database.

Comment: In that case, try creating and destroying the instance, instead of "changing" it. Destroying will be tricky because you'd want to be smart about it and destroy only if the instance is unused for some time because creating and destroying and instance for every request will be expensive.

Comment: Yeah, it seems way smarter, thanks for the reply :). So i will instantiate a new Sequelize() (with the credentials given by the customer),  then try to authenticate. if it works i will change my sequelize (variable) to this new instance ELSE keep the old one. Should works.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer
You can add config like that

```
my_instance_sequelize.config.host = 'new_xxxx'
```